# How to send JSON response from Rails to Native Application?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, native

I have two application 1 from native application (Mobile) and another is website. In mobile application, I have searching functionality.

In mobile, I have one page in that I can post my products. I can select my products through barcode scan or through web-url.

There will be two button for selecting my products barcode scan and search through web-url.

When I click on Search button, It will open web-url in webView in mobile. 
Now, I will select my products and submit the form (In RAILS).

Now, How can I pass json response to native application that my selected products will display on my post page?

Comment: Some code would have been helpful. Assuming your app makes a json request, your controller can respond by giving a JSON representation of the products as a response, basically you respond to a HTML request by rendering a view (for website) and respond to JSON by giving a JSON of the products.

Comment: simply use `return render json: {your response here}` on your product create controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can render in JSON format

```
render json: {
        :status => 400,
       :user => you_variable
      }
```